# Como dividir um número armazenado em uma string e verificar se é divisível por 495?

Tags: java, java-8

Por exemplo um numero que não cabe em um `int` e eu armazeno em uma `String`.

Como faço para ver se é divisível por 495?

Answer (score 3):

Por que não usa a classe [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) para lidar com esses números?

Você pode usar a função [`BigInteger#mod`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#mod-java.math.BigInteger-):

```
public static boolean divisivel(BigInteger numero, String divisor) {
    return numero.mod(new BigInteger(divisor)).equals(BigInteger.ZERO);
}
```

A função acima deve receber um `BigInteger` e uma *string* com o número divisor, veja um exemplo:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    System.out.println(divisivel(new BigInteger("495"), "495")); // true
    System.out.println(divisivel(new BigInteger("496"), "495")); // false
}
```

Código completo:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;

class Ideone
{
    public static boolean divisivel(BigInteger numero, String divisor) {
        return numero.mod(new BigInteger(divisor)).equals(BigInteger.ZERO);
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println(divisivel(new BigInteger("495"), "495")); // true
        System.out.println(divisivel(new BigInteger("496"), "495")); // false
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/mxWJyV)</kbd>

Comment: eu ainda sou iniciante.não tem outra forma mais facil?

Comment: @Evandro Acho que não, e usar `BigInteger` não é difícil, qual a dificuldade? Seja bem-vindo, veja o **[tour]** para entender como o site funciona!

Answer (score 0):

Pra transformar string  em int ou long tu pode fazer assim...

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = s.nextLine();
try {
   int inteiro = Integer.parseInt(str);
   long longo = Long.parseDouble(str);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   System.out.println("Numero com formato errado!");
}
```

Aqui tua variável inteiro ou longo vai ter o valor da tua string, agora é só saber se o a divisão dela por 495 tem resto zero.

```
if(i % 495 ==0){
System.out.println("É divisível");
}
```